# Erase '#' from url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, cycle, history.js

**UPDATED**

I didn't understand how to make this work so I hope you know because I didn't found more solutions:

I have implemented jquery cycle in wordpress with the window.location.hash to make an individual url from each slide (example here http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/perma.html)

Now I have an indez with some selected photos of differents categories that works with hashes like *localhost/prueba/#men/#work61*, *localhost/prueba/#women/#work15*, etc...the trick is that I have also the category */men/* and the photo #work61 permanetly cause the index may change but not the photo in the category indeed. So  what I need is change the url without reloading from */#men/* to */men/* and if they share a link they will always go to the right photo and section (did I explain it well ?)

I have been testing many ways to arrive, with history.js and even with the aisle Pushestate but I didn't found the right solution. Lately I have made this with htaccess and it's closely what I need

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /prueba/
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ $1/#$2 [NE,R]
```

This changes me from *localhost/prueba/men/work61* to *localhost/prueba/men/#work61* but if I tried to add a hash to the first folder (#men), an also only work if somebody put the link directly

Any idea? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand the URI specification, section 3.5 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5.  Essentially, in the context of a web browser displaying HTML documents, the URI fragment (after the `#`) refers to a subset of the resource (page).

Basically if you removed the `#` from your URL, you will not be referring to a different subset of the same resource, but another resource entirely.  So another page will be requested.

Comment: Thanks Lee for the URI specification. I think I didn't explained very well cause the 'problem' it's just what I need :) I modify the cycle hash to makes me this url from the home (/prueba/) where I have a slideshow with selected projects. This home will change its projects but the path will always exist in the slideshow of the specific section (men in this case). So, when users takes http://localhost/prueba/#men/work61 they will go to this slide of the home but if they takes http://localhost/prueba/men/#work61 they will go to this slideshow but in the category men and that's what I'm looking